# How to wrap IF(ISBLANK( around all formulas

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I found this VBA code on the internet. It wraps "IFERROR" around all the formulas.

```
Sub Add_IFERROR()
Dim R As Range

For Each R In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    If Left(R.Formula, 8) <> "=IFERROR" Then
        R.Formula = "=IFERROR(" & Mid(R.Formula, 2) & ","""")"
    End If
Next R

End Sub
```

I attempted to modify it so it wraps an "IF(ISBLANK(" but get a compile error.

Looking to display blank (nothing, "") if ISBLANK=TRUE, if FALSE then display whatever is in the cell.

Comment: This is generally not a good coding practice I might add.

Comment: IFNA is much better if you're trapping failed VLOOKUPS for example.

Comment: Hi CLR, the VLOOKUPS Im working with returns "0" from blank cells, for example:
1 |   | 3 | getting VLOOKUP looks like: 
1 | 0 | 3 |

Thank you for your answer, I think I understand how that particular bit of code works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ISBLANK** doesn't work the same way as **IF**ERROR. It works in the same as **IS**ERROR. It merely returns a TRUE/FALSE. To make it work in a formula, you'd use this:

```
Sub Add_ISBLANK()
Dim R As Range

For Each R In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)

     If Left(R.Formula, 8) <> "=ISBLANK" Then
          R.Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(" & Mid(R.Formula, 2) & "),""""," & Mid(R.Formula, 2) & ")"
     End If
Next R

End Sub
```

From `=FORMULA`, it would produce `=IF(ISBLANK(FORMULA),"",FORMULA)`